# Why could Aisa use observation haki from birth?

Tags: one-piece

During the fight with Enel on Sky Island, the four priests, including Enel used mantra. Later on, we learn that Mantra is actually Haki.

Luffy trained with Rayleigh to learn Haki. While Luffy was born with it, he wasn't able to use it perfectly. However, at sky island there was a kid called Aisa who used Haki to to sense people from distance. She wasn't able to perform Conqueror's Haki since she was a child, but she was able to use Observation Haki since birth. How is this possible when even Luffy couldn't do that?

Comment: I've improved the grammar in your post. If I've changed the meaning at all please edit it again.

Comment: Thnks for improving the grammar wht should i call you bro and i am new at this

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude but try to write some words in a correct form. Like 'Thnks' - 'Thanks' and 'wht' - 'what', I mean avoid using this.

Comment: It's just an opinion but based from the scenario we could speculate that Aisa is more gifted than Luffy because she was able to use Haki from birth while Luffy even though he possess it he needs someone to teach him how to use it. Aisa is a very special kid having able to use haki from birth.

Comment: Thnks for the answer bot and i'll improve it Light Yagami

Answer (score 3):

EVERYONE can train perception and armour haki, it's not a special gift. Only the emperor haki is extremely rare and only one in a million can use it (cf. http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Haki ).

Quite clearly some people are more gifted than others, and Aisa just happened to be **extraordinarily** gifted with her perception haki, as nobody trained her. She naturally mastered it, and at such a young age it's a big feat but not impossible. On the other hand, Luffy had to be trained by Raleigh himself and he most probably still isn't as good as her with his perception haki. But his personality goes better with armour and emperor haki so he specialised in those!

Similarly, to get better at sniping Usopp needs to learn perception haki, but he will probably stay weak in armour haki, while Sanji should get armour haki on his legs if he wants to be competitive...